# Rails, capture stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# config/initializers/form_builder.rb

ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.class_eval do

  def just_get_string
    yield
  end

  def with_capture
    ActionController::Base.helpers.capture{ yield }
  end

end
```

Вызываю во въюхе(slim)

```
= form_for(@some_object) do |form|
  - some_string = form.just_get_string do
    | Hello word
    -# this code outputed 'Hello word'

  - some_str2 = form.with_capture do
    | Hello word
    -# this code outputed 'Hello word'
```

Как мне вернуть результат выполнения блока (с патшала) в переменную без его вывода?

Answer (score 0):

```
# config/initializers/form_builder.rb

ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  delegate ::capture, to: :@template

  def with_capture
    capture{ yield }
  end

end
```